# Serializing several object - json representation - use array instead of list representation

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using Django Rest framework to build the server part. I have the following models:

```
class B:
    name_b = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class D:
    name_d = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class C:
    B_fk = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='B_id')
    D_fk = models.ForeignKey(D, related_name='D_id')
```

And here are my serializers using Nested Relationships ([here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)):

```
class C_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ('D_id',)
class B_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    B_fk = C_Serializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('name_b','B_id',)
```

And my view:

```
class MyView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = B.objects.all()
    serializer_class = B_Serializer
```

and I have JSON at the end like this:

```
[{"name_b": "NAME B", "B_id": [{"D_id": 130},{"D_id": 135},{"D_id": 145},{"D_id": 154}]}]
```

But I would like to have

```
[{"name_b": "NAME B", "B_id":[130, 135, 145, 154]}]
```

Is it possible? Could you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using nested representations when you want the simpler `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

Comment: @Ivan, thank you for your answer. But in this case I will get IDs of C Entities. That means **C.id** in the array. But I want **C.D_fk** (or **C.D_id**).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want nested serializers then. Default relations are using [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

```
class B_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    B_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, source=B_id)
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('name_b','B_id',)
```

Note that your model's related_name seems to be wrong as you'll need .B_id to access C instances.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this will result in Error: 'It is redundant to specify `source='B_id'` on field 'ManyRelatedField' in serializer 'B_Serializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish my comment: Actually what you're suggesting will result into `[{"name_b": "NAME B", "B_id":[1, 2, 3, 4]}]` - In the array are C.ID, but I need C.D_id, which is the field in the table C. So array should be `[130, 135, 145, 154]`

Comment: It's not a good idea to return D ids under the label of B ids

Comment: probably - I'm really new in this area... so, what is the good way to serialize one parent (B item) with several child items (Item C each of which contains FK to D)? I want B1 [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5]